# Is lightning waveform a special case of RC discharge circuit? Why is it modelled as a double exponential function?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, surge-protection, lightning, spike

As per wiki: The electric current within a typical negative CG lightning discharge rises very quickly to its peak value in 1–10 microseconds, then decays more slowly over 50–200 microseconds.

1. **Why does the lightning cause a fast rise and slow decay?** Isn't it like the discharge of a charged capacitor (~cloud) through a resistance (atmosphere) - Current is high in the beginning and gradually tapers down.

   Why is it modelled as a double exponential function instead of an exponential function?

[image]
[image]

2. With respect to lightning, most of the internet sources denote the current waveform , but [some](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=x-raw-image%3A%2F%2F%2F888dad26d38370ae1434f9854e9ff4f5f626a4ef3432b5a0e4ea806e0ab34068&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.incompliancemag.com%2FPDF%2F1001%2F&tbnid=rnCD0yatjYiHhM&vet=12ahUKEwijgKOLj-T7AhULyaACHX1tAzoQMygTegUIARDTAQ..i&docid=6U5bof2VQSMPWM&w=605&h=452&q=lightning%20waveform%20double%20exponential&ved=2ahUKEwijgKOLj-T7AhULyaACHX1tAzoQMygTegUIARDTAQ) [sources](http://vlabs.iitkgp.ac.in/vhvlab/html/pages/ivg/theory.html) denote the voltage as double exponential function. Is it correct to represent voltage as double exponential?
   [image]

Comment: Possibly because lightning happens because of ionization, which is something that does not happen when discharging a manufactured capacitor through a manufactured resistor. Air is not conductive until it becomes ionized and that takes time and it is not difficult to imagine conductivity varies with the degree of ionization.

Comment: I'm certainly no expert, but my gut says it's more like an insulation breakdown than an RC discharge. Or perhaps a *failing* capacitor, which is quite a different thing.

Comment: A cloud might be 2 km above earth. That in itself is a delay of 6.6 us plus there is an effective inductance of maybe 2.5 mH between cloud and earth to throw into the pot. I think it's an interesting question but asked on the wrong site.

Comment: I'd guess if we wanted to medel the system we'd need some quite complex model of a transmission line as well (there is aconductor over quite some distance involved, so it's probably mor like some complex RLC system. In some cases it also seems to oscillate. This sounds like a problem that would need people form Meteorology, Physics and EE...

Comment: The wave front used (~ 5 us -> ~ 100 to 500 us) relates to the tests carried out at very high voltage (some "millions" volts) where this is produced by an insulator chain - R ... Capacitors charged in parallel by the network and where the discharge (in series) is caused by a "thyratron" at the base by a single spark. This standard wave is used to test "hardware" with so-called "shock" waves. They should resemble what happens during a downward "lightning strike" (the most common)...

Comment: The wavefront of 5 us (max) is also used for the protection of substations when lightning strikes a line far enough from them. The passive "protection" of the substations is carried out by the cabling of a line of approximately 500 to 1000 meters whose characteristic impedance is much lower by construction than the characteristic impedance of the high voltage line. When the "wave front" arrives on this protection line, it is "repressed" almost entirely by this very low impedance line... and therefore does not arrive on the material which is therefore "protected".

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the lightning cause a fast rise and slow decay?

That's really a meteorological question, not an electronics engineering question.  Probably because:

1. Air is a pretty good insulator up to a point.
2. When that point is hit it becomes a pretty good conductor
3. When it becomes good conductor, the charge differential between the clouds and ground dies off.

But -- I'm guessing here.

> Why is it modeled as a double exponential function instead of an exponential function?

Again, that's really a meteorological question, but the most fundamental reason is probably because **it matches pretty well with reality**.  I suspect there's better models out there, and probably even folks working on doctorates *right now* to find even more accurate ones.

Note that you're trying to wedge some pretty strongly nonlinear phenomena into a collection of linear circuit elements -- that's just not going to work.  Clouds and air and moving water droplets are *not* going to act like resistors and capacitors and batteries like the ones presented in a beginning circuits class.

> Is it correct to represent voltage as double exponential?

Well, if the meteorologists say so, who am I to say different?  If the model fits well enough to be useful, then -- yes, you should use it, unless there's an equally useful but easier one, or an equally easy but more useful one to compete with it.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, the rise time is limited by arc resistance (a rather indefinite quantity, as dynamic resistance decreases with increasing current flow -- more heat means more ionization means more conduction), stray inductance, and radiation.

Furthermore, a cloud is not a single lumped element, but largely nonconductive itself, until lightning spreads far enough to ionize and discharge it.  Clouds aren't very different from regular air, after all (at least, that is my assumption -- any with better knowledge, feel free to chip in here).

What tends to happen is, as voltage builds, and the ionization path stretches out, at the instant a conductive path is closed, suddenly the stored voltage is applied along the entire path, causing current to ramp up rapidly.  The ramp rate is approximately given by the inductance of the path.  Inductance is proportional to length through free space, \$L = \mu_0 l\$.  Say we have \$l\$ = 1km.  \$\mu_0\$ is 1.26 µH/m, so the inductance is on the order of ~mH.  (There is a geometry factor missing here, as inductance also depends on diameter of the conductor, and how much it bends around itself.  This is just a ballpark figure.)  If the cloud is also on the order of 1km across, it will have a capacitance around 10nF, which with the above inductance, gives a time constant of \$t_{1/4} = \frac{\pi \sqrt{LC}}{2}\$ or about 5µs.  (This is the 1/4 wave time of an LC resonant circuit.)

We can also arrive at this figure in a somewhat more straightforward way simply by noting that the lightning bolt looks like a transmission line 1km long, or at light speed, an electrical length of 3.3µs.  In the right ballpark.

The exact waveform depends on the shape of the path, size of clouds and how well connected they are internally, and how much of the wave radiates into the surrounding atmosphere, versus reflects back and forth along the conductive path (as an LC resonator / transmission line stub).  This geometry is also a monopole antenna, so we expect it to radiate quite well, well enough that, if it does resonate, it's probably just for a few cycles.  So, a microsecond-scale impulse with ringdown.

So, the waveform is largely down to the fact that it's a conductive path through space -- and distance through space carries inductance, while radiation into space manifests as resistance.  And, I would guess, radiation provides more resistance than the arc itself does.  (The equivalent circuit of the radiation resistance looks something like ESR of the cloud capacitance.)

Finally, as the immediate cloud is discharged in this way, its voltage is pulled to ground (or even below, if ringing).  This puts a large electric field between it and neighboring cloud regions.  Which may in turn discharge, and so on and so forth as more of the sky becomes discharged.  This may result in a rapid-fire chain of brief impulses.  The saying goes, "lightning never strikes twice", but indeed not only does it strike highly probable locations with great ease, but the lightning bolt itself may be made up of myriad smaller strokes.  It's not uncommon for lightning bolts to last whole fractions of a second, multiple seconds even; current isn't flowing continuously the whole time, but in fits and starts, always with this impulsive waveform.

A small-scale analog of this process, is electrostatic charge on most any insulating material.  Charge it up (say by rubbing a dissimilar material against it, like the classic rubber balloon versus hair), then slide your hand over the surface, listening carefully for the quiet crackle of static discharge.  The rubber surface is an insulator, much like air or a cloud; every pop is a minute lightning bolt, discharging the local area.  Now, sliding your hand means you're manually exposing various areas to critical electric field and so causing break down; but it could also happen that this occurs automatically in an instant.  This probably explains anomalously long sparks, in such materials, or in real lightning bolts.  (Probably, a meteorologist actually knows about this, and can confirm or correct this properly.)

---

Bonus answer: there is one more facet to the waveforms used in EMC testing (surge immunity).  A typical scenario for lightning-induced transients to reach a piece of equipment, is conduction along the mains power network.  Perhaps a pole or transformer gets struck directly, perhaps merely a tree or other structure nearby.  The EMP (electromagnetic pulse), and voltage drop through the soil, elevates local power lines to a considerable voltage.  High voltage* distribution lines are normally protected with surge arrestors every couple of poles.  The nearest arrestors likely blow up (by design -- they contain a pyrotechnic charge to ensure they don't short out the line!), but the next few over will clamp the voltage to maybe triple the nominal peak voltage.

*Technically, "medium voltage".  Distribution lines are typically 4.8 to 38kV, though anything 600V to 100kV may fit the definition.  "High voltage" then is reserved for long distance transmission lines -- the kind on tall poles and pylons.

The remaining waveform after the surge arrestors still retains some peakiness (overshoot), due to the impedance of the pole's ground wire inductance, plus soil resistance; this peak could be roughly 10 times the nominal peak voltage.  The peak may fall down to a plateau level (corresponding to the clamping voltage of the arrestors), or the lightning waveform itself fizzles out before a plateau is evident and it's just a spike.

Further down the distribution line, transformers are wired in, which furnish the 120, 240, 400, 480V or other voltages that end customers use.  Transformers further filter the surge, as they do not operate instantaneously (which, as it happens, is again due, in part, to the length of wire used to wind the primary -- transmission lines show up all over electronics!).  The high voltage may also cause core saturation, in which case the surge effectively gets cut short (literally shorted out after a brief time) by this property of the transformer's core.  (So, even if the distribution line waveform has a peak then plateau shape, likely the waveform after the pole/pad transformer does not.)

It is this waveform which reaches equipment plugged into the wall.

IEC 61000-4-5 specifies a combined-wave generator, which produces a double-exponential waveform, of between 1.5/50µs (open circuited) and 8/20µs (short circuited).  The slash notation gives the 10-90% rise time, then the FWHA (full width half amplitude) duration.  This, and related standards, have been developed over the years, to be reasonably representative of real, worst-case surges that are occasionally present on the mains system.  The exact wave shape, duration and etc. may vary, but it's not likely to be much faster (due to all the above reasons), much longer (particularly because of lightning itself, and the transformers), or much taller (a couple kV at the outlet is about the worst you can expect, short of a strike very near, or directly to, the facility -- which hopefully will be an extremely rare event!).